# How to retrieve tweets with longitude and latitude

Tags: r, twitter

I'm trying to retrieve tweets with coordinates (longitude/latitude) using searchTwitter in R as below:

```
tweets <- twitteR::searchTwitter("#cancer",n =1000,lang ="en")#,since = '2015-01-01')
df <- twListToDF(tweets)
```

But all the values of these coordinates are NAs.

Any help please !!

Comment: Are you sure location is available for tweets?

Comment: yes it's possible